Update the row with exponential notation
I have a unit mm²/s. (millimeter square per second).
How to store this  exponential unit in the table row in SQL Server database?
I am getting like this mm^2. So what is way to store so that unit column look like this mm²/s.

Use a collation that allows for the storage of the character (²) in an varchar, or use an nvarchar.

I would add the Unit Of Measure captions to a separate table such as..
CREATE TABLE myUOMs (UOMID INT IDENTITY(1,1), UOM nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO myUOMs (UOM) 
Values (N'mm²/s'), (N'N⋅m')

SELECT * FROM myUOMs

Gives this..

Then in the table that stores your values/results, include a column that stores the Unit Of Measure. Then simply join to the UOM table when you need to display the results in your client app/report of whatever.
It also has the advantage of being able to change the way you present a unit in the future, by just changing it in one place.

The values in a column should normally have the same unit of measure, which is metadata not data.  So the column name should imply the unit of measure.
You can do this, eg
create table foo(id int primary key, [Expansion Rate mm²/s] float)

But you normally wouldn't, as it's hard to type the column name.  It would be more usual to note the unit externally, or embed it in the column name in a more type-able format, eg mm*mm/s.
